# How can I detect my submit button is clicked on with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, addeventlistener

Hi everyone 
 So basically I have to code a website that calculates a certain amount using javascript, here is the exemple of the website :
[Check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I21yf.png). 
 So basically the client fills the form with the quantity and I have to display the total of his command, he doesn't need to submit the form

The uncomplete code is this one :

```
<h1>Vente de Pizza</h1>
<form method="post" action="#">
    Nom du client<input type="text" name="nom" /> <br> <BR></BR>
    adresse<input type="text" name="adresse" /><br>
    <h1>Produits à acheter</h1>
    <table border = "1">
        <tr><th>Nom du produit</th>
            <th>Prix unitaire</th>
            <th>Quantité</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Pizza 4 fromages</td>
            <td>80</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="QTE1" id = "x1" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Pizza Herbo</td>
            <td>75</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="QTE2" id = "x2"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Pizza viande hachée</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="QTE3" id = "x3"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Pizza Fruit de mer</td>
            <td>120</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="QTE4" id = "x4"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
     <p font = "bold" style="font-weight: BOLD;"> Paiment par: </p><br>
     <input type="radio" name="banque" id="">Carte bancaire
     <input type="radio" name="banque" id="">Chèque <BR></BR>
        Numéro de la carte bancaire<input type="text" name="numCB" id = "x5" style="width: 400px;"/> <br><BR>
    <button class="btn" type="submit"  onkeydown = "mySubmit()" id ="bouton">Envoyer</button> <BR></BR>
     <script>
        function TotalCalculate(){
            var x1 = document.getElementById("x1").value;
            var x2 = document.getElementById("x2").value;
            var x3 = document.getElementById("x3").value;
            var x4 = document.getElementById("x4").value;
            var tot = x1*80;
            document.getElementById("Total").addEventListener("click", writeTotal);
            function writeTotal(){
                document.getElementById("Total").write(tot);
            }
        }
    </script>
    Merci de votre visite le montant total de votre commande est : 
    <input type="text" name="Total" onclick="TotalCalculate()" id = "Total"/> 
    </form>
```

So as you can see I get the value from the user and calculates the total to pay, but it doesn't show anything. laybe i need to add a listner but i can't find how to add a listner that writes something.
Please help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The event you want is `change` or `input`. For example

```js
document.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea").forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('input', TotalCalculate)
})

function TotalCalculate() {
  
  var x1 = document.getElementById("x1").value;
  var x2 = document.getElementById("x2").value;
  var x3 = document.getElementById("x3").value;
  var x4 = document.getElementById("x4").value;
  var tot1 = x1 * 80;
  var tot2 = x2 * 75;   // <-- fixed these
  var tot3 = x3 * 100;   // <-- fixed these
  var tot4 = x4 * 120;   // <-- fixed these
  var tot = tot1 + tot2 + tot3 + tot4;
  // document.write("tot");
  document.getElementById("Total").value = tot;

}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="#" onsubmit="TotalCalculate(); return false">
  <input type="text" id="x1"><br>
  <input type="text" id="x2"><br>
  <input type="text" id="x3"><br>
  <input type="text" id="x4"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<br>
total: <input id="Total">
```

Comment: Thanks for your question, I tried your code and when I fill one row and submit it, it "wipes off" all the elements in the page and it prints "tot". I also Tried to remove the "" from the code : `document.getElementById("Total").write("tot");` but it still doesn't work. Btw, i need the total to be written in the last input.

Answer (score -1):

Coucou,

You can use this if you have jQuery loaded

```js
$('#bouton').on('click', function(e){ 
e.preventDefault();
alert('clicked');
});
```

or this if its only pure JS :

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button')

button.onclick = function () {
  console.log('Click just happened')
}
```

Comment: where  in the code do I have to add it.

Comment: anywhere in your swript tag, where your javascript is. Before or after your TotalCalculate() function

Then instead of the console.log or alert i showed you, you can run you TotalCalculat function, get the result, display the total, anything you want

Comment: @NizarElaouina if this was the answer to your issue can you select as answer please ? <3

Comment: Hello, um actually, none of the answers worked for me. I'm so sure that I'm the prob! So idk what answer I should pick

Comment: But I ended solving the problem !!

Comment: what was the correct answer ?